# C# how to do arithmetic operations on a 2d Array matrix

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been toying with this code which prints a small matrix with negative and positive numbers,
I would like an efficient way to add together only the positive elements on the matrix and get the product of such elements also do the same but after a specific number, such as the highest on the matrix

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int row = 5;
                int column = 5;  
    
                int[,] array = new int[row, column];
                Random rand = new Random();
    
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                    {
                        array[i, j] = rand.Next(-5, 10);
    
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(array[i, j].ToString() + "  ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: So you could just use a if statement to check if the array[i, j] element is > 0 & > specific Number.... or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yeah that part needed some more clarification

Answer (score 0):

To filter and add positive matrix elements, you could do something like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int rows = 5;
    const int columns = 5;

    var array = new int[rows, columns];
    var rand = new Random();

    int sum = 0;
    bool numberSeen = false;
    int numberToSee = 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            var cell = rand.Next(-5, 10);

            if (!numberSeen && (cell == numberToSee))
            {
                numberSeen = true;
            }

            array[row, col] = cell;

            if (numberSeen && (cell > 0))
            {
                sum += cell;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"sum = {sum}");

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[row, col].ToString() + "  ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```